# Mouse cursor disappears

Tags: notebooks

After working on a notebook for a while sometimes my mouse cursor disappears. I can click on different cells and the text cursor will move accordingly but I just can't see the mouse cursor. Just now after having the window out of focus for a while it came back.

I don't have a system setting that makes the cursor disappear while typing, but in mathematica the cursor seems to disappear briefly whenever I press a key (so when typing continuously it blinks like crazy); could this be related?

It doesn't happen in any other program so I'm assuming it's a Mathematica glitch/feature.

I am using Mathematica 9 on Linux. I have definitely come across this problem before but I can't remember what mathematica version or OS I was using, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I sometimes have the same with Mathematica 9 on Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, so it's not just a Mathematica-on-linux problem then. Have you found any possible reason for it?

Comment: No, I couldn't think of any patterns.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP doesn't give enough information for the problem to be reproduced.