# Cursor disappears in Mathematica 9.01

Tags: notebooks

When using the template blocks from the Pallets to enter equations, the mouse cursor disappears.  It also becomes difficult to set the focus to a block in a template by clicking it.

This was also an issue in earlier versions of Mathematica for Windows.  Is there an alternative way to enter formulas or is it possible to use a third-party equation editor?

Comment: Related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40626/134) ?

Comment: Probably so - are there any known solutions?

Comment: I have tried the ShowCursorTracker but this has no effect.